# Export EDL from Movie Maker WLMP (Windows Live Media Project)

Tags: windows-movie-maker

I am editing a video and the director pre-edited some footage using Windows Movie Maker (no need to tell me how absolutely inadequate a tool MovieMaker is).

Is there some way to export something like an EDL (in any readable format, even if i have to manually convert) from a WLMP project so that i can import the project into another NLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WLMP file can be opened as an xml.  Save a copy of the project changing the extension to XML.

Convert XML to CSV using one of various free converters available online.  Open the CSV file as a spreadsheet (Excel, Calc, etc).  Now you can access the filenames and durations of each edit.

You must reformat your spreadsheet to match an EDL format supported by your NLE.  Once you have the correct format, export spreadsheet (sometimes you must convert to CSV, open in notepad and save again with the desired extension).

This is an example of the cuts once converted to csv / spreadsheet format:

```
_id,_filePath,_arWidth,_arHeight,_duration,_songTitle,_songArtist,_songAlbum,_songCopyrightUrl,_songArtistUrl,_songAudioFileUrl,_stabilizationMode,_mediaItemType
159,F:\video\img(7).jpg,2448,3264,0,,,,,,,0,2
106,F:\video\img(8).jpg,2448,3264,0,,,,,,,0,2
160,F:\video\img(50).jpg,960,960,0,,,,,,,0,2
107,F:\video\img(51).jpg,667,667,0,,,,,,,0,2
161,F:\video\clip (32).mp4,1280,720,26.026,,,,,,,0,1
108,F:\video\clip(20).MTS,1920,1080,12.69,,,,,,,0,1
```

Comment: i apologize for choosing my own answer, but, as of this time, no one came forward with a better solution and this mine workflow did work in the end.  I opened the project up in Vegas and Avid (didnt try Premiere, but surely woulda been ok, too).